# Fortumo Web SDK processing

Tags: wordpress, sms, payment, get-request, fortumo

I am setting up Fortumo Web SDK payment for my website, 
I am putting the url in  "To which URL will your payment requests be forwarded to?"

I am using some DB related code here so that it would insert the code in DB and I could check it afterwards, 
But when I test the payment it doesn't touch the GET URL and didn't send any request to this URL.

Need Support,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to solve the issue, actually the main problem is that fortumo Web SDK works only with HTTPS links and send payment response as a GET Request to the specified link at fortumo configuration.

so no my link starts with  https://multanwebtech.com/.......php